# Storing class instances in spreadsheet's cells

Tags: excel, vba

is there a way to store user defined class instances in a cell? i would like to store the instances' data somehow and preferably displaying the properties of the class

Comment: Cells may contain scalar values only, you should create a procedure for object properties storing into cells one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Cells cannot hold objects only values. Therefore you need to save all values into cells.

Add 2 procedures to your class eg `SaveToWorksheet` and `LoadFromWorksheet`. One that saves all data to a desired worksheet and one that is able to load the data from a worksheet into a instance.

So you can do something like:

```
Dim MyInstance = New MyClass
'do something with that instance
MyInstance.SaveToWorksheet "SheetName"

Set MyInstance = Nothing 'kill the instance

Dim MyNewInstance = New MyClass
MyNewInstance.LoadFromWorksheet "SheetName"
'should recreate the instance with the data from the worksheet
```

How to save/load your data depends on how your class looks like and how you desire to save the data to the sheet.

Comment: In practice, you might want to pass a Range of an open Worksheet as the parameter to the procedures or a starting Cell, rather than a Sheet Name, but +1 for the answer.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Yes, of course there is a lot of space for improvement. Actually I just wanted to give the idea along, that the worksheet does not have to be hardcoded in the class and should be kept variable to each instance.

Answer (score 0):

### Create default member of a class

- Export your class module;
- Save it as text file with *.cls* extension;
- Remove original class from your project;
- Open exported module in a Notepad;
- Add the following line `Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0`
- Specify your desired property as a default

*Example of specifying a property as a default:*

```
Property Get Value() As Long
    Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0
    Value = Whatever
End Property
```

- Save your modified file and import it back to the project

*Example of using a default property:*

```
Dim CC As CMyClassName
Set CC = New CMyClassName
CC.Value = 123
' is the same as 
CC = 123
```

[Source](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx)